# Flutter: System UI 'Location Permissions' dialog breaks the continuity of the execution of the code?

Tags: android, flutter, location, state, android-permissions

I have a project where i use the package `location`.
Everything works well, just a little problem: when the apps run for the first time and ask the location permission (using a dialog) and the user accepts, the code on flutter doesn't continues the execution.

Here is the code:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      try {
        await Provider.of<TurnActiveProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .connectSocket();
      } catch (error) {
        Provider.of<ErrorProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .showError(context, error, _scaffold);
      }
      setState(() {
        _isLoadingSocket = false;
      });
    });
  }
```

This provider line:

```
await Provider.of<TurnActiveProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .connectSocket();
```

calls and activate a socketio client and gets the user coordinates. The system shows the dialog asking permission, the user hits ALLOW and the final code:

```
      setState(() {
        _isLoadingSocket = false;
      });
```

Doesn't execute never, so the screen shows a CircularProgressIndicator forever (because the _isLoadingSocket flag never changes). If I restart my app, works without any problem. Any help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem persist. However, I found a solution and is ask for permissions BEFORE any other thing.